# Задать высоту TableView по размеру содержимого в qml

Tags: qml, qtquick

Как сделать так, чтобы высота TableView всегда равнялась высоте её содержимого и вертикальный ScrollBar был не виден(и не нужен)?

Я попробовал следующий код, но это ни к чему не привело.

```
TableView {
    id: tableView
    height: viewport.height
    model: myTableModel
}
```